# Why the code inside a class is executed when defined but a code inside a function is not executed until it gets called?

Tags: python, function, class, oop

I'm confused about this behavior,

```
def calc():
   print ("function .. calculating")



class Calc:
   print ("Class .. calculating")
```

Which generates this output:

> Class .. calculating

Why the code inside a class gets executed even if we didn't call it or create an object, while the code inside a function doesn't get executed until we call it ?

Comment: Code in a class is not very different from code outside of a class.  The code is executed, and the functions are compiled.  The only difference is the namespace.  I don't know how to explain it any better except that "that's the way it works".

Comment: If the body of a class *wasn't* executed, then the method definitions contained within it would never come into existence.  That execution could conceivably be deferred until the first instantiation of the class - but that's a lot of extra effort, that is only of benefit if you assume that programmers are in the habit of defining classes that they aren't going to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That statement is not part of any method like `__init__` or any method inside the class. As this statement is not a part of any method, the interpreter executes it before invoking the `__init__` method (implicit in this case). Invoking the `__init__` method  means when the `__init__` is called when you create an object of this class. That's why this prints it out.

Also another nice point, this would be executed multiple times when you instantiate the object. Because it is only when the interpreter is getting the class definition it executes that once. (From a discussion with Iain Shelvington)

It would be more clear from this output.

```
class Calc:
   print ("Class .. calculating")
   print(ab) #throws error
   def __init__(self):
       print('init')
```

In this case, if `ab` is not used earlier then it will throw you error. Very important thing is: the namespace it belongs to, check this:

```
class Calc:
   print ("Class .. calculating")
   ab=2
   def __init__(self):
       print('init')
print(ab) #throws error
```

Now it will again throw error. Since it is declared inside the class. But you can instantiate the object of the class and access it as something that is part of the class scope.

```
class Calc:
   print ("Class .. calculating")
   ab=2
   def __init__(self):
       print('init')

calc = Calc()
calc.ab # 2
```

You can check this for further [reference](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-definition-syntax). I want to just highlight the subtlety involved in this scope

> When a class definition is left normally (via the end), a class object
> is created. This is basically a wrapper around the contents of the
> namespace created by the class definition; we’ll learn more about
> class objects in the next section. The original local scope (the one
> in effect just before the class definition was entered) is reinstated,
> and the class object is bound here to the class name given in the
> class definition header (ClassName in the example).

Comment: The statements will be executed as part of class creation if an instance is created or not. The part about executing before invoking the `__init__` method is a bit misleading

Comment: @IainShelvington It would be executed before you initialize the object even. If I am saying something else then it is wrong. Let me read it again.

Comment: It is executed once when the class is created/defined, it will not be executed again when an instance is initialized

Comment: @IainShelvington Yes that's true. Maybe I should mention this nice point but I am just curious, was my answer indicating something else?

Comment: @IainShelvington Thanks for mentioning this. I have added that point, also this point would get clear from the reference posted above.

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with Tim Roberts. I'm not expert here but for specific below use case, the behavior is useful.

```
class Foo:
    bar = 'Baz'

print(Foo.bar)
```

This way, you can store some data and need not to instantiate it to use the underlying data.
However, if you want to use it on class instance, it is also available.

```
f = Foo()
print(f.bar)
```

Answer (score 0):

That is how the language is designed. The class body is executed when the class is defined. You can read more at docs: [9.3.1. Class Definition Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-definition-syntax)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).